# Redux "Real World" example can't run on Apache. With error "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130;"

Tags: reactjs, redux

I build the "Real World" example from  http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Examples.html. It can "npm start" and work well. But when "npm run build", and I copy the build/index.html and build/static to my Apache server root, it report "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130;" error.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plrhJ.png)

Can anyone help me?

In my host file: 
127.0.0.1 app.jogooolocal.com

In httpd-vhosts.conf file

    DocumentRoot "E:/code/app"
    ServerName app.jogooolocal.com
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
   
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

My folder structure like this:
E:/code/app/index.html
E:/code/app/static/js/main.8a6eb2e1.js
E:/code/app/static/js/main.8a6eb2e1.js.map

Answer (score 0):

The example has error.
Add `export default Root` to the end of file `examples/real-world/src/containers/Root.prod.js`

I report an error.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2036